# Transition between activities

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a really strange behaviour for the transition between two activities. There's a green background that can be seen on the top when I am starting another activity. Both layouts have black background so I don't know from here it can come. I changed the colorPrimary, windowBackground to black, and that green still appears.

I believe it's something related to the Theme but I really don't find what attribute should I set.

Let's say I'm in FirstActivity, I call startActivity(..SecondActivity) -> the image below represents how the transition look like on the top of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Provide a [mcve]..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

When you use a custom transition for switching activities, the color of the background while animation is done is `colorPrimaryDark`. 
I changed this to black and all works good now.